# R: get qualifying rows from data?

Tags: r

I have a CSV with a bunch of data like so:

```
> test.csv <- read.csv("~/Desktop/stats.csv")
> test.csv
          m                   lvl a     b           c a_pct  b_pct  c_pct   d_pct
1    543557                    2A 13  255  59.6666667  18.8   10.2    1.6     5.1
2    545059                    2A  0   19   4.0000000  15.8   15.8    5.3    10.5
```

I want to be able to do a histogram of like `a_pct` using `hist(test.csv$a_pct)` but only on qualifying rows, where like `c_pct` > 20 or `c` < 200, etc. Sort of like a SQL WHERE clause. Is there a way to do this easily in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
hist(test.csv[test.csv$c_pct > 20 | test.csv$c < 200, "a_pct"])
```

Two notes:

1. A data.frame is indexed by [rows, columns], where you can specify anything to select out the specific rows/columns.
2. You need to use `|` instead of `||`, since the former is vectorized.

Comment: I'm running into trouble using a string. Something like: `[test.csv$lvl = '2A', "a_pct"]` but that fails. Any ideas?

Comment: It's not the string.  `=` is used for assignment, `==` is for logical comparison.  Read through `help("<")` for more information.

Comment: Is this faster than subset()?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is just:

```
with( test.csv, hist( a_pct[ c_pct > 20 ] ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at ?subset

```
hist(subset(test.csv, c_pct > 20 | c < 200, select=a_pct))
```